# Select where no value is greater than X

Tags: sql

I'm currently running this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.FormName
  FROM PatientTask as pt
    INNER JOIN ClinicTask ct 
               ON pt.fTaskKey = ct.fTaskKey
    INNER JOIN Form f 
               ON ct.fFormKey = f.FormKey
 WHERE pt.TaskTargetDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01');
```

Now, clearly this is just going to return `FormName` that have a `TaskTargetDate` that is earlier than January 1st 2012. What I'm trying to do is find `FormName`s that do not have a `TaskTargetDate` which exists in the last 2 years. So if there's a form with a `TaskTargetDate` in 2010, 2011, and 2013, it should be excluded entirely from the query return because of that 2013 date.

Essentially I'm looking for old forms which are no longer being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NOT IN` should give you those results:

```
Select DISTINCT f.FormName
   FROM Form f
   WHERE  f.FormKey NOT IN
   (
       SELECT ct.fFormKey
           From PatientTask as pt
           Inner Join ClinicTask ct on pt.fTaskKey = ct.fTaskKey
           WHERE pt.TaskTargetDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01')
   )
```

Also the `CONVERT` is not necessary - SQL will automatically parse `'2012-01-01'` as a date since it's being compared to a date value

Answer (score 1):

You can use left outer join:

```
Select 
    DISTINCT f.FormName, pt.fTaskKey 
From 
    Form f left outer join ClinicTask ct 
    on ct.fFormKey = f.FormKey 
    Inner Join 
        (
        select fTaskKey 
        from PatientTask
        WHERE pt.TaskTargetDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-01-01')
        ) pt 
on pt.fTaskKey = ct.fTaskKey
where ct.fFormKey is null
```